# iOS checkboxes and radio buttons default components

Tags: interface-design, ios, lists

I have a question regarding the default component for checkboxes and radio buttons in iOS.

[Context]

*In this flow, the user will have to create a two period charging recurrence (for a service), where he has to select the day (day of month) for the first period and then, for the second period, either a specific day (day of month) or a number of days before the end of the month, for the charge to take place.*

*The user also has the possibility to define optional service period settings (here is where the checkbox comes in), like the type of the charge (if it's an in arrears or in advance payment) or custom start / end date for periods.*

I want to create a screen, on iPad, having both checkboxes and radio buttons, but using the default components from the iOS doesn't really help, because the UI used by Apple, it's the opposite of the "common UI" (checkboxes have the UI of radio buttons and radio buttons are a check icon with no box around it). I've attached this wireframe in order to better understand the context in which these components are displayed.

[image]

The issue here is that the users can't really understand which is a radio button and which is a checkbox, which makes it harder for the user to have a first read of the screen and understand what's happening.

Only after they randomly tap on the screen they can figure out the behavior of the list:

[image]

Do you have any suggestions on how to apply an alternative of using these components but in a more intuitive way?

LE: this app is used by Android users also (on a company device), this is why the UX should accommodate both OS' in an Apple environment.

Comment: Hi Phreak, Welcome to Graphic Design StackExchange. We hope you enjoy sharing knowledge and experience.

Comment: I'm confused by your use of the word 'period.' As a duration, period has a starting time, length, and ending time. I normally wouldn't ask a user to specify a period for a start. I would ask for a start time or date to commence. The same for the ending. Alternately, I might ask for a start time or date, and then the length of the duration. Explanations can help with the app. execution although at the expense of elegance. Please re-examine your question phrasing.

Comment: Thanks for the welcoming and feedback, Stan! Highly appreciated! The idea behind the flow is more complex than it looks so that's why I didn't want to get in details. The main point was to find an UI solution which presents checkboxes and radio buttons, in the same screen, in such a way that the difference between them is understood (and also the fact that one is optional and the other is mandatory).